# How to make jquery CSS manipulation synchronous (i.e. without callbacks)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asynchronous, callback

So basically I have css that causes an element to get bigger (increase height) when it hovers.  I want to be able to have a function that allows you to click the element, disable the hover functionality (by setting the height back to it's normal state with .css()), fire a different segment of code, and then set the hover height back to normal when done.  Since .css() doesn't have a callback functionality, I'm kind of stumped regarding how to do this.

Here's a jsfiddle that kind gives the layout of what I want to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/lennox02/99KB2/3/

And here's the lines of code in question

```
//this fires first, disabling the hover height of 200px;
$(".single-item:hover").css({"height":"100px"});

//the code I want to fire, fires second
$("#6").html("Hello");

//after the code finishes firing, put the hover height back to how it was    
$(".single-item:hover").css({"height":"200px"});
```

Comment: Wait, so you want that when somebody hovers, div is expanded. Then 'hello' appears. Then the div height is restored. All within the same hover?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. What's do you mean by "disable the hover functionality (by setting the height back to it's normal state with .css())" and "then set the hover height back to normal when done" isn't that the same? And maybe that's only for the example but why IDs should start with a letter.

Comment: It's not the `.css` that needs a callback, but the "*fire a different segment of code*". What exactly is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it's closer to what you want http://jsfiddle.net/99KB2/6/ but probably not exact. You might have to look into JavaScript callbacks if this isn't good enough.

```
$(".single-item").on('click', function() {
    //this fires first, disabling the hover height of 200px;
    $(this).css("height", "100px");

    //the code I want to fire, fires second
    $("#6").html("Hello");
});

$(".single-item").on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).css("height", "");
});
```

Also, it's much easier to use all jQuery events instead of mixing JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, this is my bad, but my real world problem actually uses checkbox's for the onclick event (so, no mouseout possible).  Also, the css HAS to fire before the main code.  My actual problem is a plugin called isotope.  Basically, I'm dynamically changing the values isotope works with, but when I do that the hover css messes with the sites layout.  Basically, I'm trying to stop the hover, update isotope, and then reset the hover, all via a checkbox onclick event.

Comment: Oh wow, sorry, I just realized the mouseout would work since the hover is tied to the parent element of the checkbox. Still, though, the initial css change HAS to happen before the main code.